# True or false about recursion

Tags: recursion

I am working on a quiz for a computer science course. I would like to check that the following statement is false:

> A recursive call may never generate more than one recursive call for
>   the recursion to terminate

We have put this statement as false and I would like you to confirm that it is false. In almost all cases it is false, isn't it?

Comment: See this question:  [True or false about recursion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/378161/true-or-false-about-recursion).  :-)

Comment: Consider the classic (and inefficient) recursive fibonacci also: `f(n) { return n <= 1 ? n : f(n-1) + f(n-2); }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is false.

Think about how recursive operations might behave in a binary tree for example.